# How to Replace All the "nan" Strings with Empty String in My DataFrame?

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have `"None"` and `"nan"` strings scattered in my dataframe.  Is there a way to replace all of those with empty string `""` or `nan` so they do not show up when I export the dataframe as excel sheet?

Simplified Example:

**Note:** `nan` in `col4` are not strings

```
ID  col1   col2   col3   col4
1   Apple  nan    nan    nan
2   None   orange None   nan
3   None   nan    banana nan
```

The output should be like this after removing all the `"None"` and `"nan"` strings when we replaced them by empty strings `""`:

```
ID  col1   col2   col3   col4
1   Apple                nan
2          orange        nan
3                 banana nan
```

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you looking for [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)?

Comment: Why are the `nan` values in `col4` retained in the expected output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a list of strings to replace with blanks strings that won't affect actual `nan`'s...

```
df.replace(['nan', 'None'], '')
```

Which'll give you a new dataframe of:

```
ID   col1    col2    col3  col4
1  Apple                   NaN
2         orange           NaN
3                 banana   NaN
```

Answer (score 8):

Use pandas' NaN. Those cells will be empty in Excel (you will be able to use 'select empty cells' command for example. You cannot do that with empty strings).

```
import numpy as np
df.replace(['None', 'nan'], np.nan, inplace=True)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Replacing with '' consumes a lot of memory so this should be the acceptable solution.

Answer (score 4):

You can compare each column to the numpy object dtype (which is basically text columns), and then only do replacements for those columns.

```
for col in df:
    if df[col] == np.dtype('O'):  # Object
        df.col1.replace(['None', 'NaN', np.nan], "", inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

All those loop-de-loop solutions...

```
replacers = [None, np.nan, "None", "NaN", "nan"] # and everything else that needs replacing.
df.loc[:, df.dtypes == 'object'].replace(replacers, '', inplace=True)
```